# Nested Dynamic block on counted resource not working as expected

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Need your kind help. I am stuck with the following resource creation. Using Terraform v1.0.6

I need to create appropriate subnets dynamically in two VPCs

variables.tf

```
vpc_resource_networks = {
  pnw-01 =  [
    [
      {
        subnet_name   = "wb-01"
        subnet_ip     = "10.58.72.0/25"
        description   = "WEB01"
        index         = 0
      },
      {
        subnet_name   = "wb-02"
        subnet_ip     = "10.58.72.128/25"
        description   = "WEB02"
        index         = 1
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        subnet_name   = "wb-01"
        subnet_ip     = "10.58.80.0/25"
        description   = "WEB01"
        index        = 0
      },
      {
        subnet_name   = "web-02"
        subnet_ip     = "10.58.72.128/25"
        description   = "WEB02"
        index        = 1
      }
    ]
  ]

}
```

main.tf

```
locals {
  wlb_net   = element(keys(var.vpc_resource_networks), 0)
}

resource "aws_subnet" "wlb" {


  count = length(module.aws_vpc_app_resource)
  vpc_id = element(module.aws_vpc_app_resource.*.vpc_id, count.index)
  dynamic "subnet_group" {
    for_each = var.vpc_resource_networks[local.wlb_net][count.index]
    content {
      dynamic "subnet" {
        for_each = subnet_group.value
        content {
          cidr_block = subnet.subnet_ip
          availability_zone  = element(var.azs, subnet.index)
          tags = {
            Name = subnet.subnet_name
          }
        }
      }
    }

}
```

I intend to create subnets dynamically which is var.vpc_resource_networks.pnw01[0] should be on one vpc and other index on another VPC.
The above block returns

dynamic “subnet_group” {
Blocks of type “subnet_group” are not expected here.

Please assist

Comment: The `aws_subnet` resource does not contain a `subnet_group` block as confirmed by the error message and the documentation. It also appears that in your theoretical `subnet_group` there are arguments belonging to the `aws_subnet` resource itself. It seems as if the first issue to recity here is to remove the dynamic block entirely.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work for info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the resource definition of [aws_subnet](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/subnet), I can see that, as the error message suggests, there's no property for a "subnet_group".

There are several different resource types that are subnet groups though for different services; such as DMS, DocumentDB, DAX, Elasticache, MemoryDB, Neptune, RDS, and Redshift. Search the term "subnet_group" on the left panel within the [provider page](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/subnet).

Perhaps an AWS expert can comment here but I believe you're trying to do two things in one motion here.

First you should create the subnets and define their ranges, then you should create subnet groups that need access to different subnets for a particular service.

[Here's some more information on subnets and subnet groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/SubnetGroups.html).

Comment: Thanks for checking this. Btw the "subet_group" is a label for the dynamic expression.  It could be any name. I am not using the property .https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

Comment: @Floki Dynamic blocks create a block with the name you give it if I'm not confused. So this would create an resource aws_subnet with a block inside it of subnet_groups {}. If subnet is the actual property then remove the subnet groups section and just have the dynamic subnets?

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it. My understanding of dynamic block was not correct. You are right.